# Creating and saving a thumbnail in array using php

Tags: php, arrays, image

I am new to php and I need help. I am trying to make a simple image gallery. I am done with uploading part of my gallery. Now I want to **get those images from a folder**, **make their thumbnails** and **save them in an array** so that I can display them later.
This is what I am struggling with so far. The array remains null at the end.

```
$folder = 'images/';
$filetype = '*.*';
$files = glob($folder.$filetype);
$count = count($files);
$thumbArray = array();

 for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
 if(($img = @imagecreatefromstring($files[$i])) !== FALSE) {

    $width = imagesx($img);
    $height = imagesy($img);

    $boxSize = min($width,$height);
    $boxX = ($width / 2) - ($boxSize / 2);
    $boxY = ($height / 2) - ($boxSize / 2);
    $thumbArray[$i] = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 100);
    imagecopyresampled($thumbArray[$i], $img, 0, 0, $boxX, $boxY, 100, 100, $boxSize, $boxSize);
 }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is in this line:

```
if (($img = @imagecreatefromstring($files[$i])) !== FALSE) { ... }
```

It seems that statement was never been executed.

To obtain an image from a file using it's filename, you should use `imagecreatefromjpeg` function. So your code inside loop should look like:

```
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($files[$i]);

$width = imagesx($img);
$height = imagesy($img);

$boxSize = min($width,$height);
$boxX = ($width / 2) - ($boxSize / 2);
$boxY = ($height / 2) - ($boxSize / 2);

$thumbArray[$i] = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 100);
imagecopyresampled($thumbArray[$i], $img, 0, 0, $boxX, $boxY, 100, 100, $boxSize, $boxSize);
```

At the end, you can use `imagejpeg` function to see the result in browser, or directly save it to a file.